# Serve content generated by a script with Apache

Tags: apache-httpd

Suppose you have a domain that is pointed to your server's IP.
As soon as it reaches your server's IP you use Apache to point it
to a DocumentRoot (in a VirtualHost).

But instead of pointing it to a document root, can you point it to a script?
I want the script to control what is displayed on the web, not the DocumentRoot.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you're referring to Python you can probably achieve what you want by using a WSGI Python script and connect that to Apache through [mod_wsgi's WSGIScriptAlias](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIScriptAlias). Most WSGI middlewares provide some kind of router functionality that you can use to select, based on URL prefixes and other parameters, what to display.